# Is there a Wordpress core & plugins update action hook?

Tags: hooks, updates

I would like to run several actions on a website once WP core or any of the plugins have been updated using the built-in update process. Is there a way to do it?

I would prefer if I could run commands on 3 different cases:

1. WP core update is finished
2. A single plugin update has been
   finished
3. A bulk update for plugins has been finished (so that I
   run the command only

after all of them have been finished)

Comment: Any progress on this question? Ever?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had a chance to try out your solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Hooks

The hooks you're searching for are

```
'pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins'
```

and

```
'upgrader_post_install'
```

The later takes three arguments. Example:

```
function upgrader_post_install_cb( $true, $hook_extra, $result )
```

and should be used for: Move & activate the plugin, echo the update message.

### Moving plugins

Moving works like this:

```
$wp_filesystem->move( 
     $result['destination']
    ,'your_destination_path'
);
```

Then use `activate_plugin( 'path/file' );` after moving.