# Hook before & after plugin / core update

Tags: plugins, hooks, upgrade, core

I'm working on a maintenance plugin for my website and I want to enable it before plugin/core upgrade starts and disable it after plugin/upgrade ends.

Any ideas ? Thanks! :)

PS: all I know is I can use "update_feedback" hook after core upgrade ends

Comment: I think here is something which can help you.
Some hooks which work when WordPress core is upgraded. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65626/is-there-a-wordpress-core-plugins-update-action-hook

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Wordpress core & plugins update action hook?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65626/is-there-a-wordpress-core-plugins-update-action-hook)